# Writing to the Database with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

This is about as beginner as a question gets, but I can't find anything in the ruby docs or on google that helps.

It's a very simple question; how do I commit an ActiveRecord object to the database?

I have my **user.rb** file in **models** which just contains the two lines;

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I have a **users** table in postgres that has only two fields, **id** and **email**.

And I have the following line in my signup controller;

```
User.new(:email => email)
```

It doesn't kick an error so I assume that the new User object is created just fine, and that it's happy about being given an 'email' field, which leads me to believe that it is correctly reading its own field list from the database, but no record is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do two things to persist an object to the database:

```
User.new(:email => email).save
```

Or:

```
User.create(:email => email)
```

You're right that this is a fairly beginnery question, but that's nothing to be ashamed of! You should probably read the [Ruby on Rails Getting Started Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) which introduces this and many more helpful concepts.

Comment: Many thanks, I will also read the guide - I'd skipped out a lot of the RoR 101 type guides as they seem to cover a lot of ground I'm familiar with having been a PHP dev for a number of years. Just need a jump-start into ruby I guess.

Comment: while you're here, I assume I can use the User object to then pull back out the id (autoincrement) field after I have run the **save** function?

Comment: Yep, something like this: ```@user = User.create; @user.id```

Comment: If you want to know if the save failed (perhaps due to validations failing), you can use the 'bang' versions of the above - e.g. `User.new(:email => email).save!` See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html#method-i-save-21 for more.

Comment: `You're right that this is a fairly beginnery question, but that's nothing to be ashamed of!`
We need more folks like you. Thank you for keeping people's confidence up.